# Distances between countries based on borders in R?

Tags: r, distance, geography

I am trying to calculate the distances using `rnaturalearth`.

```
library(rnaturalearth) 
kr =  ne_countries(returnclass="sf")
d = st_distance(kr[128,],kr)
```

but the following error appear:

```
Error in s2_geography_from_wkb(x, oriented = oriented, check = check) :  
 Evaluation error: Found 3 features with invalid spherical geometry.  
 Loop 2 is not valid: Edge 175 crosses edge 178  
 Loop 1 edge 3 crosses loop 2 edge 1  
 Loop 2 edge 0 crosses loop 6 edge 3.
```

Comment: Use the "r" tag if you are looking for help with any R code - I've added it for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sf` package tries to treat lat-long data as if it made up of great-circle segments connecting points, using spherical geometry. Most geo data is constructed treating lat-long data like its a flat geometry. Interpreting lines between points as curves or straight lines in lat-long space leads to errors like this.

You can switch off this spherical geometry handling with:

```
> sf_use_s2(FALSE)
```

And then the distance computation works:

```
> d = st_distance(kr[128,],kr) 
> d[,1:4]
Units: [m]
[1] 3404071.8 5985371.2  725718.3 3724227.7
```